# Do I need to replace #14 wire on a 20A breaker in my garage?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, junction-box, circuit

Should I replace the 14/2 wire in my garage that powers two 15A outlets?

These junction off of a 12/2 main line that also powers outlets for garage door motor, plug in overhead LED lighting, and modern dryer (5 connections total). This circuit uses a 20Amp breaker.

I'm assuming the junction to the dryer outlet is a continuation of the 12/2; and that the garage motor outlet (part of the junction box, stacked on) likely uses 14/2.

Comment: Or this? [Can I use 14 gauge wire on a 20 AMP electrical circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/157206/35141)

Comment: Or this? [Replacing receptacles and found 14 AWG in a 20 amp circuit. Advice?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/189444/35141)

Comment: Or this? [20 amp breaker with 12 gauge and 14 gauge wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/58027/35141)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace the 14 AWG wire with 12 AWG wire. All wire on a 20A circuit must be 12 AWG or larger. The alternative is to change to a 15 A breaker, but with that much stuff I'd want to keep it 20A.

Comment: In addition to replacing the 14 AWG with 12, since you already know you have a wiring issue, it's possible that other incorrect wire sizes have been used for this circuit.  So you'll probably want to check everything else as well on this circuit to make sure everything in the circuit is 12AWG.

Comment: I will replace the wire then. Is there any issue with it if left unused (nothing drawing current from those outlets) until then?

Comment: Technically yes, it should be disconnected. Realistically as long as nobody plugs in a space heater, not a problem.

Comment: Please flag obvious duplicates. With two gold badges in the subject you know what they are.

Comment: @isherwood valid point though my excuse this time is I answered from my phone, but I suppose I was only able to do that because I've answered similar before

Comment: "Siri/Google, search diy.stackexchange.com for 14 gauge wire on 20 amp breakers" results in a list almost identical to mine above. :P

Comment: Isher thanks for the clarification. I’m using the site on my phone and the search icon wasn’t as obvious the first time. The auto suggestion while titling the question didn’t seem to suggest the same thing from my point of view (ignorance).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 14 gauge on a 20 amp breaker.

The two options is to replace with 12 gauge or change the breaker to 15 amps.

Are you sure the dryer is on the same circuit?  Usually dryers are on their own circuit.  Unles the dryer is quite tiny and only uses a few amps(5), I would make sure it is on its own circuit/breaker.

Comment: If "modern dryer" refers to a heat pump dryer or a small apartment size dryer, it *might* be on a standard 120V circuit.

Comment: It's not clear also if the dryer is an electric heat dryer or gas.  If it's a gas dryer, having it on a 120V 20A circuit seems reasonable, since the electrical only needs to provide motor and control power and not any heat elements.

Comment: The dryer is gas. But has smart features.

Comment: Thank you for the response @crip659. Is there any issue with these being connected, but not used? Otherwise I will open up the junction and remove/replace any 14 gauge.

Comment: The only way to make sure they are not used is to remove them.  Somebody in the future will use them.